Has anybody seen a certificate store in Chinese letters?
I have a Windows 11 host with a certificate store in Chinese letters. The system language is German:
快呀牲牯漠数楮杮挠彷楠楦慣整狒潴敲
(This translates to: Hurry up, the beasts will be scratched in the desert, and they will be scratched imitating the old man.)

Has anyone seen this before?
Where does it come from?
Do applications usually add certificate stores?

screenshot
Edit:
It seems this store is related to Rustdesk, which I installed recently. Googling the store name as given by certutil -enumstore (佒呏䔀牲牯漠数楮杮挠牥楴楦慣整猠潴敲›) gives a result: reddit
Is there a method in Windows, such as auditing, to find out who created it, and which certificates were installed?

Hi is it a managed computer ? Check a collègue to see if they have the same one. The fact it’s a store make it odd, maybe a goo from a distant domain targeted you, or you got infected by something maybe.

In case anyone is wondering, Google Translate renders this as "Hurry up, the beasts will be scratched in the desert, and they will be scratched and beaten in imitation of the old man." This sounds like a piece of a traditional story rather than anything computer related.

This could be incompetence on the part of the vendor, or a supply chain compromise. The "installer" has dodgy practices, including installing unknown root CA certificates with no explanation. Probably worth noting that the application is purportedly "remote desktop" app.  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39256493 https://github.com/rustdesk/rustdesk/discussions/6444

In my certlm.msc I see the same store. Somewhere I read that it is created my Rustdesk, which I have installed. I copied these 'chinese' characters to a text file and saved it as UTF-16LE (using VS Code). Then I opened the text file in a hex editor (HxD) and was able to read the following text:

Since this store is empty, I'm going to delete it. See, if it affects Rustdesk, which I might have to reinstall (or deinstall).

Thank you for researching this funny story of the modern IT world :D

Thank you for the supply. Would you mind to let us know, how you deleted the certificate store?

@Thomas I hadn't actually deleted them when I wrote this post, and it took me quite a while to find a way, because you can't handle their names in Powershell or cmd. I used regedit to delete them, they are stored somewhere below the following keys: HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates and HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates, easily spotted by their chinise names.  The usual warning: If you are unsure and are not familiar with Regedit, don't do it and leave it to an expert. Errors are irreversible and can destroy your Windows.
